# Including httplib2

Tags: python, google-app-engine, httplib2

So I was having the usual problem with importing httplib2, I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17007034/importerror-no-module-named-httplib2-app-engine-1-8-0) and similar answers. But now I must be bold, and ask a dumb question, how do I include/link the modual into my project?

Comment: What Python version are you using 2 or 3 etc?

Comment: App engine Python does not support Python 3, but 2.7.3 !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the link you posted to states **httplib2** is not a standard library that comes with Python you have to install it first.

To install **httplib2** in Python 3 you can use (Ubuntu):

```
sudo apt-get install python3-httplib2
```

or pip

```
pip install httplib2
```

Other instructions for direct download here: http://code.google.com/p/httplib2/wiki/Install

Then make sure it's on your PYTHONPATH.

Then just include it:

```
import httplib
```

Comment: I'm on a mac with python3, sorry, but you were partially right. pip didnt work for what ever reason but I followed your link used python setup.py install to install it. But how do I include it in my PYTHONPATH, I'm working in Eclipse so I know right click properties and what not but I'm not sure there httplib2 ends up after the install.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sudo pip3 install httplib2

import httplib2
```